# Error in SQL Insert Into Statement

Tags: database, ms-access

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert into DDTable" _
& "Values NewMember.ApplicantName, NewMember.ApplicationNo, NewCustomer.ApplicationNo, NewCustomer.PlanName, NewCustomer.AccountNo, NewCustomer.InvestmentAmount, Deposit.InvestmentAmount, NewMember.ProcessingFee, NewCustomer.ProcessingFee, NewMember.IntroducerName, NewMember.IntroducerCode" _
& "SELECT NewMember.ApplicantName, NewMember.ApplicationNo, NewMember.ProcessingFee, NewMember.IntroducerName, NewMember.IntroducerCode From NewMember" _
& "Union All Select NewCustomer.ApplicationNo, NewCustomer.PlanName, NewCustomer.AccountNo, NewCustomer.InvestmentAmount, NewCustomer.ProcessingFee From NewCustomer" _
& "Union All Select Deposit.InvestmentAmount From Deposit" _
& "WHERE NewCustomer.OpeningDate =#" & dtpDates.Text & "# AND Deposit.Date =#" & dtpDates.Text & "# AND NewMember.JoiningDate =#" & dtpDates.Text & "#", con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

The above code showing "Error in Insert Into Statement", I just can't find out why! Please help. Thanks

Contd:
Now I have a working SQL code that inserts records into my database table and the code is below...

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT NewMember.ApplicantName, NewMember.ApplicationNo, NewMember.ProcessingFee, NewMember.IntroducerName, NewMember.IntroducerCode, NewMember.JoiningDate, NewCustomer.ApplicationNo, NewCustomer.PlanName, NewCustomer.AccountNo, NewCustomer.InvestmentAmount, NewCustomer.ProcessingFees, NewCustomer.OpeningDate, Deposit.Date, Deposit.InvestmentAmount Into DDTable  FROM NewMember, NewCustomer, Deposit WHERE NewMember.JoiningDate = NewCustomer.OpeningDate AND NewCustomer.OpeningDate = Deposit.Date;", con)
```

But the recent problem is that, when I am using DateTimePicker to select any date then records are not getting saved. Any Idea, Any Help?

Comment: Have you tried putting that code into a sql testing device? that is quite poor sql if i understand it at all.

Comment: The line continuation doesn't add a space.  So the query expands to "Insert into DDTableValues"...

Comment: You should probably post your new question as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

Several problems:

1. You have both a VALUES clause and a SELECT clause in the INSERT.  You can only have one or the other.
2. The VALUES clause does not have parens around the list of values, which is required.
3. You do not specify a list of columns into which to insert data so you better hope the number and order of columns in the table matches whatever you specify in VALUES or SELECT (whichever you decide on).  I'm guessing, by the way, that you have confused the VALUES clause with the list of columns.  The column list has no keyword that precedes it but does need parens around the list of columns.
4. You are using UNION as if it were JOIN.  If you mean JOIN you should rewrite the SELECT statement.  If you mean UNION, you need to produce the same number of columns in the UNIONed SELECTs.  (hint: You really mean JOIN).
5. You are not including a space at the end of each line, so you have text running together in a way that will be unintelligible to the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no SQL guru or anything but my understanding of union is to join two queries together into a single recordset, by the looks of your query your trying to join multiple tables together for records into a single query and insert into a table, in which case you should use `INNER JOIN` or possibly `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` depending if your other tables can possibly not have data for a records and could be blank.

Another issue is with your string concat.  You dont have any whitespace at the end of your strings causing them to be `DDTableValues` instead of `DDTable Values`

In any case this looks more like the query your looking for:

```
INSERT INTO DDTable ([NewMember.ApplicantName], [NewMember.ApplicationNo], [NewCustomer.ApplicationNo], [NewCustomer.PlanName], [NewCustomer.AccountNo], [NewCustomer.InvestmentAmount], [Deposit.InvestmentAmount], [NewMember.ProcessingFee], [NewCustomer.ProcessingFee], [NewMember.IntroducerName], [NewMember.IntroducerCode])
SELECT NewMember.ApplicantName, NewMember.ApplicationNo, NewCustomer.ApplicationNo, NewCustomer.PlanName, NewCustomer.AccountNo, NewCustomer.InvestmentAmount, Deposit.InvestmentAmount, NewMember.ProcessingFee, NewCustomer.ProcessingFee, NewMember.IntroducerName, NewMember.IntroducerCode
FROM NewMember
INNER JOIN NewCustomer ON NewMember.<identifier> = NewCustomer.<identifier>
INNER JOIN Deposit ON NewMember.<identifier> = Deposit.<identifier>
WHERE NewCustomer.OpeningDate = <date> AND Deposit.Date = <date> AND NewMember.JoiningDate = <date>
```

The `<identifier>` refers to the field in the tables to link all the records together whether it be a CustomerID or MemberID or something else.

Note:  Another thing I just noticed is your VALUES list you using table name, a period, and field name; I don't know if your tables field names are actually 'NewMember.ApplicantName' or if you just put that in your example, I'm not entirely sure MSACCESS allows periods in field names, in which case your VALUES list should look more like

```
INSERT INTO DDTable ([ApplicantName], [ApplicationNo], [PlanName], [AccountNo], [InvestmentAmount], [ProcessingFee], [IntroducerName])
```

Your VALUES list also contains a lot of duplicate fields by the looks of it such as

```
NewMember.ApplicationNo AND NewCustomer.ApplicationNo
NewMember.ProcessingFee AND NewCustomer.ProcessingFee
NewCustomer.InvestmentAmount AND Deposit.InvestmentAmount
```

If so, depending on how your fields are named that could be a problem that needs to be addressed.

Comment: A MySQL guru is unlikely to be of any help to someone using MS Access as the dialects are quite different.

Comment: Point taken, I meant SQL guru in general.  I've dabbled with both so I know of some of the little differences and functions in both.  Only my second day as a registered member so I have to remember to look at the tags in questions to see what language/program they are referring too.